# How to make falling div clickable?

Tags: javascript

I've made words in falling div, example of my code is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/apHLu/674/embedded/result/

But I can't understand why I can't make words in div's clickable. Sometimes I can click it and I see alert message with word, but sometimes I should click the above word to see alert message. Maybe it is because this animation way is very slow?

Main part of my code:

```
/* Start by creating a wrapper div, and an empty img element */
var leafDiv = document.createElement('div');
var image = document.createElement('div');

/* Randomly choose a leaf image and assign it to the newly created element */
image.innerHTML = phrase[counter];
image.style.padding = "40px 0 0 20px";

leafDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
leafDiv.setAttribute('data-url', counter);
leafDiv.setAttribute('data-text', phrase[counter]);

leafDiv.onclick = function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-text'));
};


leafDiv.style.top = "-100px";
```

Answer (score 0):

i edited your fiddle and solved it here: http://jsfiddle.net/apHLu/675/

```
/*    
    // YOUR OLD METHOD
    leafDiv.onclick = function () {
        alert($(this).attr('data-text'));
    };
*/

// MY SUGGESTION
leafDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data-text'));
});
```

binding `click` events on animated dom elements is a bit tricky, and as you see, it's difficult to "catch" them.

in these cases it's much better to bind `mousedown` or `mouseup`. in this case i think `mouseup` is preferred.

take a look and see if it's what you meant.

hope that helps.